# offline_message_hook: does not get called when one sends an offline message

Tags: ejabberd

I am developing, chat application for android using ejabberd as XMPP server. I want to send GCM push notification, when user is offline. For that I am creating new module in ejabberd, registerd offline_message_hook, but this function gets called only when somebody starts typing and finishes typing. Below are the only packets passed to this hook. Although, user receive message when he/she comes online.

```
Packet: {xmlelement,
      "message",
      [{"type",
       "chat"},
      {"id",
       "purple7d4d0773"},
      {"to",
       "xxx@rakshith"}],
      [{xmlelement,
       "paused",
       [{"xmlns",
         "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"}],
       []}]}
Packet: {xmlelement,
      "message",
      [{"type",
       "chat"},
      {"id",
       "purple7d4d0773"},
      {"to",
       "xxx@rakshith"}],
      [{xmlelement,
       "composing",
       [{"xmlns",
         "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"}],
       []}]}
```

Comment: Hi can you share your gcm module ?

Comment: Hi @TolgayToklar, I don't have the actual implementation with me at the moment. However you can implement [GCM push](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=gcm+implementation+in+erlang) using [offline hook in ejabberd](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ejabberd+offline+hook). Hope that helps!

Comment: Where do you store android device token ?

Comment: @TolgayToklar using ejabberd archive module one can archive all the messages, you may need to extend the module or you can write your own. In any case the archive module gives more insight into how to work with database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things about hooks in ejabberd:
1) The callbacks are called always in order, the order is defined by the priority you specify when registering it.
2) If a callback return 'stop' it prevents the event to be propagated to the rest of the listeners on the chain.

What is happening is that the ejabberd offline module is listening in the offline_message_hook, the same than your code.  It handles the message, and returns 'stop', so your code isn't executed.

(your code do receive the message for the chatstates notifications because those are ignored by the offline module, and so it don't stop the chain in those cases).

You probably wants your code to be run *before*  the offline storage module. Just remember to not return 'stop' so the offline module has the oportunity to store the message.

Comment: thanks, currently the order is 50, I will change it to 1 and let you know. BTW what is the default order of offline module?

Comment: mod_offline register itself with 50 as well.  If you use the same priority, which one is called first is undefined (currently the name of the module and function callback are taken into account, but better to consider the situation as undefined)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes if the order changed to 1 it works like charm. :D